# Why does every df value change when using Spark regexp_replace()?

Tags: regex, apache-spark, pyspark, null, regexp-replace

I want to use `regexp_replace()` in PySpark to convert all question marks and back slashes in my data frame to null values. This is the code I used:

```py
question = "?"
empty_str = "\\\"\\\""

for column in df.columns:
     df = df.withColumn(column, regexp_replace(column, question, None)
     df = df.withColumn(column, regexp_replace(column, empty_str, None)
```

However, when I use this code *all* the values in my dataframe turn into null values - not just the question marks and back slashes. Is there a way I can change my code to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `regexp_replace` you cannot replace values to null, you will need another method, e.g. [`replace`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.replace.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.replace)

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = spark.createDataFrame([("?",), ("\\",), ("b",)], ["col_name"])
df.show()
# +--------+
# |col_name|
# +--------+
# |       ?|
# |       \|
# |       b|
# +--------+

pattern = r"^[?\\]+$"
df = df.withColumn("col_name", F.regexp_replace("col_name", pattern, "")) \
       .replace("", None, "col_name")
df.show()
# +--------+
# |col_name|
# +--------+
# |    null|
# |    null|
# |       b|
# +--------+
```

In your attempt, every value changed to null, because you incorrectly provided None to the `replacement` argument, instead of `str`. Only str is accepted, according to the [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.regexp_replace.html#pyspark.sql.functions.regexp_replace).

> pyspark.sql.functions.regexp_replace(*str: ColumnOrName, pattern: str, **replacement: str***) → pyspark.sql.column.Column

Answer (score 0):

it is working like this, ou have to use \\ to replace backslash with null and ? to replace Question mark with null

```
>>> df.show(truncate=False)
+-------------------------------------------------+
|_c0                                              |
+-------------------------------------------------+
|"{""id"\":""e5?2f247c-f46c-4021-bc62-e28e56db1ad8|
+-------------------------------------------------+

>>> df.withColumn("_c0",regexp_replace('_c0','\\\\','')).withColumn("_c0",regexp_replace('_c0','\?','')).show(truncate=False)
+-----------------------------------------------+
|_c0                                            |
+-----------------------------------------------+
|"{""id"":""e52f247c-f46c-4021-bc62-e28e56db1ad8|
+-----------------------------------------------+
```